# Android LinearLayout within LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I tried to make a simple layout like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Only the first TextView ("hello") is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make `layout_height` of inner layout `wrap_content`.

Comment: Ah you are right. Currently it's taking up all the space of it's parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your second `LinearLayout` is set to `fill_parent` in the layout's height.  This is causing it to push out everything that's below it that was placed into the first `LinearLayout`.  Change it to `wrap_content` and it should work.